# erro de retorno ao consumir Api (usando fetch) via javaScript

Tags: javascript, api, get, fetch

Estou tendo problemas para consumir a api, sempre tenho erros nos retornos do js.
OBS: Os dados são ficticios, pois é uma api interna do meu sistema

```
Exemplo da api: http://pokemon.teste.com:199985/super?user=pokemnn&password=ash&tipo=app

username: "Moreira"
password: "#2022*pokemon"
```

fiz o seguinte no meu js:

```
const url = "http://pokemon.teste.com:199985/super?user=pokemnn&password=ash&tipo=app";
const username = "Moreira"
const password = "2022*pokemon"


function getAllPosts() {
    const response = await fetch(`${url} /${username}/${password}`, {

        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
}

getAllPosts()
```

porém, não consigo obter os dados, ele consta um erro no

```
const response = await fetch(`${url} /${username}/${password}`
```

Comment: Fala Lucas, teria como botar o código da função que manda esses dados também? Pra saber como que o link esta pegando os dados, porque desse jeito parece que além de ter queries de user e password, tem que botar eles dnv no path, ou seja:

`http://pokemon.teste.com:199985/super?user=Moreira&password=2022*pokemon&tipo=app/Moreira/2022*pokemon`

Answer (score -2):

Lucas, nessa situação, não tenho a informação de como está seu servidor, e como funciona a função que retorna os dados, então estou te mostrando uma solução que imagino ser a correta:

1. Primeira coisa que eu percebi de cara foi essa URL que estava meio confusa, porque existem queries específicas para user e password , não precisando utilizá-las depois em um path ('/'). Desse jeito que você estava utilizando `${url} /${username}/${password}`, a URL ficaria assim: ***http://pokemon.teste.com:199985/super?user=Moreira&password=#2022*pokemon&tipo=app/Moreira/#2022*pokemon***,
   repetindo duas vezes o user e o password. Acabei contornando isso apenas substituindo as queries da própria URL :

```js
fetch(`http://pokemon.teste.com:199985/super?user=${username}&password=${password}&tipo=app`)
```

2. Como sua chamada é um GET, você não precisa declarar no fetch nem `method: "GET"`, porque é o padrão, nem o `headers: {"Content-type": "application/json",},` . Dessa forma o código ficou assim:

```js
const username = "Moreira"
const password = "2022*pokemon"

function getAllPosts() {
  const response = await fetch(`http://pokemon.teste.com:199985/super?user=${username}&password=${password}&tipo=app`);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}

getAllPosts()
```

Comment: Entendi, e como passo a Authorization?

Comment: Então, a sua user e password , você esta passando na própria url através daquela query `user=${username}&password=${password}`, imagino que seja isso.

Comment: Consegui, vou postar o resultado na resposta, muito obrigado

Answer (score -3):

Consegui resolvero o problema, passando as informações da seguinte maneira

```
const url = 'http://pokemon.teste.com:199985/super?user=pokemnn&password=ash&tipo=app';

const credenciais = btoa("Moreira:#2022*pokemon");



async function getAllPosts() {

    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Basic ${credenciais}`
        },
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
}


getAllPosts()
```